# How to .replace from a line to another in a .txt, if the line to be replaced is above the line where i'll get the value for replacement?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, text, replace

First of all, sorry for my long title.. i couldn't explain it in a simple way.. feel free to edit it!

I need some help with the logic to solve my problem...

### I have a .txt file with the following characteristics:

1. Each line corresponds to a specific operation...
2. Each field of the line is delimited by a "|" separator
3. My .txt have 120k+ lines, but only 60k~ are for my invoices
4. I have to copy the values from the lines that starts with C195, and replace them in a specific field of the C100 line that is immediatly above the C195 line.

**Example:**

> The invoice's part of my .txt is like:
>
> - |C100|1|1238761|128,82|1002,21|0,00|**0,00**|**0,00**|**0,00**|
> - |C170|1|414859|Mini Leitoa|Kg|21,80|KG|
> - |C190|363,53|0,00|0,00|0,00|0,00|0,00|0,00|
> - |C195|C195|1|Base de Cálculo ST: **193,56** - Valor da ST: **10,10**|
> - |C195|C195|2|Valor do IPI: **7,10**|
>
> What it was supposed to be:
>
> - |C100|1|1238761|128,82|1002,21|0,00|**193,56**|**10,10**|**7,10**|
> - |C170|1|414859|Mini Leitoa|Kg|21,80|KG|
> - |C190|363,53|0,00|0,00|0,00|0,00|0,00|0,00|
> - |C195|1|Base de Cálculo ST: **193,56** - Valor da ST: **10,10**|
> - |C195|2|Valor do IPI: **7,10**|

### What I did until now:

1. Created a program to read the lines of my txt and store them in `input_lines = []`
2. Get the `index()` of the lines in the `input_lines` that starts with C100, and store them in `pos_c100 = []`
3. Since my C195 field can have either values of the Tax1 (ICMS) or Tax2 (IPI), i used `re.search(param,string)` to find if the line contains either "ICMS" or "IPI".
4. If the line contains "ICMS", it will contains 2 values: the first one is the `icms_basis` and the other is the `icms_value`

   - |C195|1|Base de Cálculo ST: 193,56 - Valor da ST: 10,10|
5. If the line contains "IPI", it will contains 1 value: only the `ipi_value`

   - |C195|1|Valor do IPI: 10,10|
6. I've extracted the values out of the string using `re.findall()` and stored them in a "tax specific dictionary" with the line position

Since each value have a specific position to be replaced, and I already know these positions, I created 2 dictionaries to hold the index of the C195 line and their values, one dic for IPI and another for ICMS.

**My data layout:**

```
pos_c100 = [line_c100]
dic_icms = {line_c195 : [icms_basis, icms_value]}
dic_ipi = {line_c195 : ipi_value}
```

**What I got after running my script now, for example:**

```
input_lines = ["|C100|1..", "|C170|1..", "|C195|1|IPI..", "C195|1|ICMS.."] #the output of `file.readlines()`
pos_c100 = [2, 4, 8, 10] #the positions of the lines that start with C100
dic_icms = {6 : ["200,15", "15,80"]} #{key, [icms_basis, icms_value]}
dic_ipi = {7 : "7,15"} # {key, icms_}
#key is the position of the lines that startswith c195 in input_lines
```

> Using the above `dic_icms` for example:
>
> How can I get the `"200,15"` and the `"15,80"` from the `dic_icms`,
>   that is located at the line in the 6th position of the `lines_input`, and
>   replace it in a specific position of the line in the 4th position of
>   the `lines_input` using a loop in my dictionaries?
>
> I need a way to check if the line is the closest above and if so,
>   replace the value referring to the dict values...

maybe with a

```
for key in dic_ipi:
    for item in pos_c100:
        dists = []
        dist = key - item
        dists.append(dist)
```

and

```
linha = (linha[0:posInicialBcICMS] + linha[posInicialBcICMS:posFinalBcICMS].replace("0,00", ICMS_BASIS) + linha[posInicialVlrICMS:posFinalVlrICMS].replace("0,00", ICMS_VALUE) + linha[posInicialVlrIPI:posFinalVlrIPI].replace("0,00", IPI_VALUE) + linha[posFinalVlrIPI + 1 : len(linha)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with reading the file:

```
file = open("blabla.txt", "r").
data = file.read()
file.close()
```

Out data contains whole text. By using `split`:

```
data = data.split("\n") #splitting by \n
```

you will get big array looking like this: `['line1', 'line2', 'line3'...]`. We need to create new table:

```
new_table = []
```

And Now it's time for heavy operations. Since your line looks like `|C170|1|414859|Mini Leitoa|Kg|21,80|KG|` you can use `split()` once more:

```
for line in data:
    new_table.append(line.split("|") # split returns new table splitted by "|". Append adds this table to new_table in the last position.
```

`new_table` looks like this: `[[line1_element1, line1_element2, line1_element2], [line2_element1, line2_element2, line2_element3],...]`. Now you should be able to use `len()` function to get length of specific table. For example:

```
for i in xrange(0, len(new_table)): # iterating through lines, but 'i' is integer type from 0 to len(new_table)
    for j in xrange(len(new_table[i])): # iterating through each element in 'i' line (i is index of new_table)
        print new_table[i][j] # this will print j element of i line in new_table
```

If you can acces every element in every line by it's index, you can easli compare everything by using `if` statement. For example:

```
if new_data[i][j] == "C165":
    do_something()
```

Hope it helps.
--EDIT--
You were asking about closest line. It will be `i` or `j` element +- 1.